# Pull data summing up the amount column such that the result is grouped by customers, month and year

Tags: sql, laravel, database, eloquent, group-by

I have a **customers table** and a **customer transactions** table.

This is the customers' table below.

[image]

This is the customer transactions table below.

[image]

This is what I want to achieve below:

[image]

I want to be able to sum up the amount column such that the result is grouped by customers and month and year.

This is what I've done so far:

I created a model for both **Customers** and **Customers transactions**. I have this relationship in the Customer transactions model:

```
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }
```

I also have a Customer controller where I have the logic to fetch the data. In my CustomerController file:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $transactions = CustomerTransaction::with('customer')->get();

        dd($transactions);
    }
```

Comment: I was able to resolve it.
In the CustomerController file, this is what I now have in the index method:

```
        $transactions = CustomerTransaction::with('customers')->selectRaw('customer_id, sum(amount) as amount, MONTH(date_created) as month, YEAR(date_created) as year')
        ->groupBy('customer_id', 'month', 'year')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Please, I need to write it in a plain SQL query to be able to achieve the expected result. Can someone help me with that, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to write the SQL query:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select null)) as id,
name as `Customer name`,
sum(amount) as `Total amount`,
concat(YEAR(date_created), '-',
lpad(MONTH(date_created), 2, '0')) as `Year month`
from customer_transactions
join customers on customers.id=customer_transactions.customer_id
group by `customer_id`, `Year month`
order by `customer_id`, `Year month`
```

Comment: It works 100% fine now

Comment: Incase there is any improvement to make, you can paste it here, please

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it. In the **CustomerController** file, this is what I now have in the index method:

```
$transactions = CustomerTransaction::with('customer')
->selectRaw('customer_id, sum(amount) as amount, MONTH(date_created) as month, YEAR(date_created) as year')
->groupBy('customer_id', 'month', 'year')
->get();
```

Then in my view, I have this:

```
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>S/N</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Year month</th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach ($transactions as $transaction)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $transaction->customers->name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $transaction->amount }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $transaction->year }}-{{ sprintf('%02d', $transaction->month) }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
```

Comment: This works using laravel eloquent but I need it in SQL query. Anyone can assist with that, please?